# bool value of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, boolean

what is the best way to turn a list into bool value? I am looking for something like:

```
return eval_bool(my_list)
```

I have a custom container in which I implement the `__nonzero__` method which is supposed to work like this:

```
if self.my_list:
    return True
return False
```

But is it pythonic enough? :) Anyway, I am curious how Python interprets the value of the list in the `if` statement because this code works differently:

```
return my_list == True
```

J.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use:

```
bool(my_list)
```

Which evaluates it as Python "truthiness" and returns a real Boolean.

Comment: While `bool` can be used, it's more Pythonic to just call `if my_list:` and let Python determine whether `my_list` should evaluate to `True` or `False`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: Why is `if my_list: return True\nreturn False` more pythonic than `return bool(my_list)`?

Comment: It's just not common to write `if bool(my_list):` when you can also write `if my_list:`. In most cases, you only need to check whether the list is empty or not, you don't really need a boolean value. Python can see that you're evaluating an if statement and it calls `bool()` itself. If you really then a boolean value (for example, as output) then `bool(my_list)` is fine of course.

Comment: @SimeonVisser the goal here is not to have conditional logic at all, but to *return* a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

99.9% of the time, performance doesn't matter, so just use `bool(my_list)` as [Keith suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850253/364696).

In the cases where performance *does* matter though, the nature of `bool` means it's actually quite slow, at least on the CPython reference interpreter. It has to go through generalized function call paths, to generalized constructor paths, to generalized argument parsing for 0-1 arguments (and in [all but the most recent versions of Python](https://bugs.python.org/issue29695), checking for keyword arguments), all to eventually just increment as reference count on a singleton and return it.

You can see how much this costs with `ipython` microbenchmarks (on my Windows x64 3.6.3 build):

```
In [1]: %%timeit -r5 l = []
   ...: bool(l)
   ...:
118 ns ± 0.808 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [11]: %%timeit -r5 l = [1]
    ...: bool(l)
    ...:
117 ns ± 0.306 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

It may not be obvious, but even on my relatively weak laptop, 117-118 nanoseconds just to determine truthiness is a bit much. Luckily, there are a couple other options. One is to abuse syntax to go through a dedicated path for truthiness evaluation (from here on out, I'll just test the empty `list`, the timings are basically identical either way):

```
In [3]: %%timeit -r5 l = []
   ...: not not l
   ...:
25 ns ± 0.289 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

That's a vast improvement; it takes roughly one fifth the time. On Python 3, using `True if l else False` also works with equal speed, but it's much slower than `not not` on Python 2, where `True` and `False` aren't protected literals, just built-in names that must be loaded dynamically each time.

Still, it's not perfect; sometimes you *need* a callable, e.g. to convert a lot of values to `bool` via a callback function (e.g. with `map`). Luckily, [the `operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) has you covered [with `operator.truth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth); while it's still a callable with all the overhead that entails, it's not a constructor, it takes *exactly* one argument (not 0-1), and it doesn't allow keyword arguments, all of which cost a surprising amount on the CPython reference interpreter. So when you can't use implicit truthiness testing or syntax based conversion with `not not`, and you still need the speed, `operator.truth` has you covered:

```
In [4]: from operator import truth

In [5]: %%timeit -r5 l = []
   ...: truth(l)
   ...:
52.1 ns ± 1.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Twice as long as `not not`, but if you're using it with built-ins that call it repeatedly (like `map`) being able to push all the work to the C layer, avoiding byte code execution entirely, can still make it a win, and it's still well under half as costly as `bool()` itself.

Reiterating my earlier point though: ***99.9% of the time, performance doesn't matter*, so just use `bool(my_list)` as [Keith suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850253/364696).** I only mention this because I once had a scenario where that boolean conversion really was the hottest point in my code (verified through profiling), and using implicit truthiness testing (not even converting, just returning the `list` with the caller doing `if myfunc():`) shaved 30% off the runtime, and returning `not not` of the `list` still got nearly a 20% savings.

Answer (score 1):

If `len(my_list) == 0` it is returned as `false`, otherwise it is `true`. It is completely pythonic to write:

```
return len(my_list)
```

which although it is returned as an integer, evaluates as `true` for non zero lengths, and false otherwise.

Comment: That will return the integer value, however, and we want a boolean.

Comment: it works but it violates pep 8: For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false. Yes: if not seq: if seq: No: if len(seq) if not len(seq)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary "if" operator. Google says it supported since 2.5

```
foo = True if your_list else False
```

Comment: Note: In Python 2, at least for the CPython reference interpreter, this is surprisingly slow, because both `True` and `False` are global built-ins that must be loaded from the built-in namespace (which involves a pair of dictionary lookups, one for globals, then a second in builtins when they're not found), not literal constants. In Python 3, they are literal constants, which only require a cheap `LOAD_CONST` instruction to load (which boils down to a single C level array lookup), so this is one of the two fastest ways to convert to a `bool` (the other being `not not your_list`).