# pop() method in python lists doesn't work properly

Tags: python, list, built-in

When I execute the following code in Python 2.7.3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = []


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()


class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()


c = C()

print c.b.a.s

c.b.a.s.append(1)
c.b.a.s.append(2)
c.b.a.s.append(3)
c.b.a.s.append(4)
c.b.a.s.append(5)

print c.b.a.s

for element in c.b.a.s:
    print c.b.a.s.pop()

print c.b.a.s
```

I get the output:

```
[]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
5
4
3
[1, 2]
```

But I expect the for statement pop all the elements in the list and leave c.b.a.s as [].

**The question:**
I omit something in the code or is something wrong in pop() method?

Comment: Try `for i in range(len(c.b.a.s))` instead

Answer (score 4):

you should not modify a list as you iterate it!

try

```
for _ in range(len(c.b.a.s)):
    c.b.a.s.pop()
```

instead

Comment: I would expect it to fail as truth value of a non-empty array is ambiguous ...  meh or maybe im making that up...

Comment: Truth values are not ambiguous! See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: @SuperUser: While both of these will work (and, before anyone raises the objection, be fast enough that performance probably doesn't matter), they have different connotations to a human reader. So, do the one that expresses what you mean.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: numpy arrays are, intentionally, not sequences or collections. What you're arguing is equivalent o saying that `a + b` doesn't return `b` appended to `a` for two sequences because it returns something different for numpy arrays.

Comment: im not arguing ... im just saying I remembered why I didnt think truth values of non-empty arrays, and ensuring I wasnt totally crazy.  I obviously now get that Truth values of python arrays are non-ambiguous :)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an iterable object while iterating it using a for loop is usually a bad idea unless you really understand its underlying implementation.  Instead, use a looping construct such as the following:

```
while len(c.b.a.s):
    element = c.b.a.s.pop()
    print element, c.b.a.s
```

Comment: `len` is unnecessary in this case, as a list will evaluate to _True_ if not empty, so `while c.b.a.s:` runs about the same speed as `for _ in xrange(len(c.b.a.s)):`. calling `len` seems to be only 25% slower, however.

Comment: im not sure thats always true ... Im sure Ive gotten error messages about truth value of non-empty array being undefined, however Im not sure under which cases that fails ...

Comment: [bool-value-of-a-list-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850245/bool-value-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think [this](http://ideone.com/dQc7IM) is the most simple and elegant way to do with Python. _ variable, range(), xrange() and len() functions just overload uselessly the code.

Comment: `len` doesn't need to recompute, because it's stored within the `list`. Don't leave it off because of performance reasons, because they're almost certainly irrelevant in any real-life use case. Leave it off because it makes the code longer and more complex for no benefit.

Comment: bah turns out im full of bad advice on this thread :P ... sorry :) thanks abarnert :)

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, the problem has nothing to do with your class structure. What's happening is a how you're using pop. Since you're actively modifying the list you're iterating over, the internal index for the current iteration will eventually exceed the actual size of the list, causing the for loop to exit.

If you want to empty a list using pop, you should find out how many times to run pop (ie, size of the list) and run it that many times:

```
for el in xrange(len(c.b.a.s)):
   c.b.a.s.pop()
```