# Behaviour of all() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

```
>>all([])
True
>>all([[]])
False
>>all([[[]]])
True
>>all([[[[]]]])
True
```

The documentation of all() reads that it returns True is all the elements are True/For an empty list.
Why does all(**[ [ ] ]**) evaluate to False?
Because **[ ]** is a member of **[ [ ] ]**, it should evaluate to True as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>all([])
True
```

because all iterables the list are True (there are zero iterables though)

```
>>all([[]])
False
```

there is one empty iterable (innermost empty list) which would evaluate to `False`

```
>>all([[[]]])
True
```

the only iterable here ( `[[]]` ) has one empty list inside of it, and hence evaluates to `True`

```
>>all([[[[]]]])
>>True
```

same as above

Answer (score 12):

The docstring for `all` is as follows:

> `all(iterable) -> bool`
>
> Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
>   If the iterable is empty, return True.

This explains the behaviour. `[]` is an empty iterable, so `all` returns True. But `[[]]` is *not* an empty iterable; it is an iterable containing one item, an empty list. Calling `bool` on that empty list returns False; so the entire expression is False.

The other examples return True because the single item is no longer empty, so it is boolean True.

Answer (score 2):

Lists in Python evaluate to `True` if and only if they are not empty (see, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850265/1106415)).

`all` returns `True` if and only if each one of the elements of its argument evaluates to `True`.

For the first example, your list is empty, and `all` returns `True`.

In the second example, the list's only element is an empty list, which evaluates to `False`, therefore `all` returns `False`.

For all the other examples, the list's only element contains further lists, and therefore isn't empty and evaluates to `True`, so `all` has to return `True`.